# Android Permission denied for window type 2007

Tags: java, android, view, permissions, window

i am using this library in my project : https://github.com/recruit-lifestyle/FloatingView

And i am getting this error :
[Click here for picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ken2.png)

this library not working on marshmallow and nougat .

Codes :

```
 final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(bCon);
  final ImageView iconView = (ImageView)     inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_chathead, null, false);

 final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
         final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)bCon.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
         windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
         mFloatingViewManager = new FloatingViewManager(bCon, this);
         mFloatingViewManager.setFixedTrashIconImage(R.drawable.ic_trash_fixed);
         mFloatingViewManager.setActionTrashIconImage(R.drawable.ic_trash_action);
         final FloatingViewManager.Options options = new FloatingViewManager.Options();
         options.overMargin = (int) (16 * metrics.density);
         mFloatingViewManager.addViewToWindow(iconView, options);
```

Comment: @EJoshuaS   Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootlmpl$W@b003ace -- permission denided for window type 2007

Answer (score 1):

This library uses `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission

From android M onwards Every app that requests the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission and that is installed through the Play Store (version 6.0.5 or higher is required), will have the permission granted automatically for the app.

If instead the app is not installed from play store, the permission is not automatically granted. You will have to manually ask for this permission at runtime like other dangerous permissions are handled from Android M and above.

Comment: how can i get system alert window app on google play? i didn't find

Comment: Its not an app. It means if your app uses that permission then it will automatically be given if its downloaded from play store. But if you install from somewhere else, you will have to ask permission manually through code.

Comment: ok, then how can i get system alert window on play store ? because not installed

Comment: @TahsinVural as Kapil said it is permission not an app ... there is nowhere that you can download it .

android use permissions to allow your app use android features like camera, sd cards and ... 
from android version 6 some of this permissions marked as dangerous permissions and you have too grant it at runtime

check this link
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting